# Transform config file without key or name attributes

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-config, app-config, slowcheetah

I want to transform some attributes but I can't add a name or key attribute to use xdt:Locator="Match(name)" or xdt:Locator="Match(key)".

For example, I could have:

```
<parentElement>
    <children>
        <add key="ExampleKey">
            <thing attribute="blablabla"></thing>
        </add>
    </children>
</parentElement>
```

How could I replace the thing attribute "blablabla" by another value?

UPDATE 1: in addition to that, I can't insert other attributes in the "thing" markup because it throws some errors via the dll that uses the attribute.

UPDATE 2: it appears that I had to use SlowCheetah, and then it worked well. Thanks to the preview, I found out I can add xdt:Transform="Replace" to the parent element, just like this:

```
<parentElement xdt:Transform="Replace">
    <children>
        <add key="ExampleKey">
            <thing attribute="blablabla"></thing>
        </add>
    </children>
</parentElement>
```

And now it works perfectly! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can find the element using an XPath expression with a `Condition` locator instead of `Match`, as described in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326%28VS.100%29.aspx). i.e.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parentElement xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <children>
    <add>
      <thing attribute="falala" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Condition(@attribute = 'blablabla')"></thing>
    </add>
  </children>
</parentElement>
```

Comment: Thank you! Why not but unfortunately, in my example I can't modify the thing element because it throws an error in the DLL that uses the attributes. I updated my question.

Comment: @LéoDavesne not sure I understand - the code in my answer goes in your transform file - e.g. `Web.Release.config` - and the resulting transformed file should not have any additional attributes added.  It is possible that I didn't fully understand your question, so you may need to add some more details about your setup. e.g. is this a Web.config transform, or some other file using [SlowCheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5), or something else?

Comment: Ok so I finally used SlowCheetah and I can preview transformations. So I could visualize my tests and found out I can add xdt:Transform="Replace" to the parent element. Thank you for you help! I'll update the question.